# (Minecraft) In the old 1.7.10 version of the M.C.A mod, can I have two husbands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I think I have read somewhere that if you are monarch you can marry two people at the same time. Is this true? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I read the description of the mod I have and have never seen "Monarch" anywhere. But, you can still do it. You use the crystal ball twice in different areas, choose a family in one section, a village in the other, and the person in the family house will automatically be your spouse. You are allowed to marry someone again from the village.